# How to hide the Sign On Paper button using DocuSign SOAP API

Tags: docusignapi

I've already asked the question but the answer I received concerned the REST API which didn't help me. Here is my situation:

- Platform: .NET
- API: SOAP (using the Visual Studio generated client)

I'm using the embedded signing and creating an envelope based on a template and in the EnvelopeInformation I set EnableWetSign to false. When I get to the document as a user, I still have the "sign on paper" button.

Is removing that button just not supported by the SOAP API?

Comment: This is working just fine for me using SOAP API and simply setting EnableWetSign to false.  Posting a solution in a minute...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set **EnableWetSign** to false in your envelope.  Make sure you have spelling correct and all of that, for instance if you spell it enableWetSign instead of EnableWetSign it won't hide the button and you won't get an error either.  It's probably also a good idea for you to inspect the request you're sending out and make sure the property is indeed being set to *true*.

I just tested and this is what works for me.  I've been testing with PHP code, you can get the same code I'm using by downloading the DocuSign SOAP SDK from GitHub.

Here's the start of my PHP send function that works for me:

```
function createEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndFormsSample() {
    global $api;
    global $AccountID;

    // Configure and envelope information
    $envInfo = new EnvelopeInformation();
    $envInfo->AccountId = $AccountID;
    $envInfo->EmailBlurb = "testing DocuSign creation services";
    $envInfo->Subject = "create envelope from templates and forms sample";
    $envInfo->EnableWetSign = false;

...<more code>...

}
```

Comment: Ok, I think this was an account configuration issue.  The option to Sign On Paper had been enabled on your account, but the ability to override that (through the API) was not enabled, so the button was always showing.  Please try again and accept solution if it works now.